# Remote Invoke-Command to Remove-WindowsFeature does not work as module not available

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, invoke-command

I have created a powershell session from a Windows 10 machine (client) to a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine (server) and try to uninstall a feature:

`$session | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Remove-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell }`

I receive the error:

```
Invoke-Command : The term 'Remove-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

If I RDP to the server machine and start powershell, the command is available, but on the client machine it is not and there is no module `ServerManager`.

This implies that the command I am trying to run at the server needs to somehow be available on the client, which seems bizarre to me.

Have I missed something?

Comment: `Invoke-Command` does not accept `PSSession` by pipeline.

Comment: That was it! Although the error did not point to it, passing the session as a parameter gets it working. How do I mark you as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-Command` does not accept value for `-Session` parameter by pipeline. By pipeline it accept input objects, which would be passed to invoked command:

```
12345 | Invoke-Command { "Pipeline input: $input" }
# Pipeline input: 12345
```

As your command does not have any target for remote invocation, `Invoke-Command` invokes command on local computer. Since local computer does not have requested command, it produce error about that.